# AppleScript Terminal App to sort IP Addresses

Tags: terminal, applescript

Basically I want to be able to have an AppleScript terminal application that prompts for a text file that contains IP addresses, then sort the IP addresses, and output the result.

This is the code that I have so far:

```
do shell script "sort -n -t . -k 1,1 -k 2,2 -k 3,3 -k 4,4" & (choose file)
```

No idea where to go from here really. 
Getting the following error, as well:

> sort: stray character in field spec: invalid field specification `4,4Macintosh'

**EDIT: I figured it out, decided to just save the sorted output back into the original file.**

**Here is the final code:**

```
do shell script "sort -n -t . -k 1,1 -k 2,2 -k 3,3 -k 4,4 /Users/<USERNAME>/Dev/IP-Blacklist/blacklist.txt -o /Users/<USERNAME>/Dev/IP-Blacklist/blacklist.txt"
display dialog "Sorting Complete!"
```